# PyQGIS. Field calculator based on the rank of another field

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am trying to make a script to calculate a field "rank" [RANK] based on the feature rank in another field "population" [POP]. My current script can found below. In this script, I created a new field "RANK".

The idea is that the city with the highest number of people will have the highest number in the field [RANK], namely 10. The city with the lowest number of inhabitants will have the lowest number, namely 1. So the idea is a kind of sorting number.

---

```
fn = path to the file

layer=iface.addVectorLayer(fn, '', 'ogr')
features=layer.getFeatures()
caps=layer.dataProvider().capabilities()

if caps&QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
       res=layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("RANK", QVariant.Double)])  
   layer.updateFields()
```

Comment: I am trying to rank 10 different cities (features) based on the field "population" [POP]. For this I created a new field for the ranking order [RANK]. 

The idea is that the city with the highest number op people will have the highest number in the field [RANK], namely 10. The city with the lowest number of inhabitants will have the lowest number, namely 1. 

So the idea is a kind of sorting number :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() # layer to work with
populationfield = 'population' # name of existing population field
rankfield = 'rank' # name of new rank field

request = QgsFeatureRequest()
# setup the orderby request: ascending=True -> smallest city will have rank 1, ascending=False -> biggest city will have rank 1
orderby = QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause(populationfield, ascending=True)])
request.setOrderBy(orderby) # set the request to the order by clause
rankcounter = 1 # initialize counter

with edit(layer):
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(rankfield, QVariant.Double)]) # add the new field
    layer.updateFields() # update the fields, so we can work with the new field added
    
    for feature in layer.getFeatures(request): # iterate over the sorted layer
        feature[rankfield] = rankcounter # assign the current rank to feature
        layer.updateFeature(feature) # update the feature
        rankcounter += 1 # increase rank counter
```